# How to validate a password with my following condition? Any function?

Tags: ios, swift, passwords

1. It must have a capital letter.
2. It must contain at least one number.
3. It must contain a punctuation mark.
4. It cannot have the word "password" in the string.
5. It must be longer than 7 characters and shorter than 31 characters.

Examples

Input: "passWord123!!!!"

Output: false

Input: "turkey90AAA="

Output: true

I tried following code,

```
func SimplePassword(_ str: String) -> String {

  let password = self.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespaces)
    let passwordRegx = "^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&<>*~:`-]).{8,}$"
   let passwordCheck = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@",passwordRegx)
    return passwordCheck.evaluate(with: password)

  return str

}
```

Comment: Please show your attempt and explain any specific problems you are having.

Comment: you are in the right way , where you struck.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a non-regex variant for validating the password, I would argue that it is easier to read and maintain than a regular expression solution.

```
func isValid(password: String) -> Bool {
    return (8...30).contains(password.count) &&
        password.rangeOfCharacter(from: .uppercaseLetters) != nil &&
        password.rangeOfCharacter(from: .decimalDigits) != nil &&
        password.rangeOfCharacter(from: .punctuationCharacters) != nil &&
        !password.lowercased().contains("password")
}
```

Note that in your example you say that "turkey90AAA=" should return true but '=' is not a punctuation mark so the above code will not accept it. Instead this character is a symbol so if you want to include it then also add a check against the `.symbols` character set, `password.rangeOfCharacter(from: .symbols) != nil`