# Validate Username with regex

Tags: ios, swift, regex, nspredicate

I am in the process of developing a registration form. It has the following requirements:

- can contain uppercase and capital letters, numbers, and character set
- must not contain spaces
- length from 5 to 16 characters

I will check the string like this.

```
extension String {

    var isValidUsername: Bool {
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@ ", "^(?=.*[A-Za-z0-9!@#$%^&*()._-]).{5,16}$")

        return predicate.evaluate(with: self)
    }

}
```

Now there are 2 problems I can enter the spaces, although I should not. I can use characters other than those listed. How do I fix this?

Comment: Just don't use a regex, the whitespace constraint can easily be done without, same goes for the length constraint. There really is no point in using regex here.

Comment: Consider approach like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66003170/5318223

Comment: You put  (any characters). In the regex, you should escape it : \. And also suppress . before {5,16}

Comment: Another alternative to regex, https://stackoverflow.com/a/62425699/9223839

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, a regex still can be used here as there are only two things to fix:

- The `.` pattern used at the end of the regex matches any char but a line break char hence it can match really a lot of chars
- The lookahead `(?=.*[A-Za-z0-9!@#$%^&*()._-])` just requires at least one char listed in the character class after any zero or more chars other than line break chars. To only allow chars from the lookahead, use the lookahead character class instead of `.` in the consuming pattern.

**NOTE** the anchors are redundant since `MATCHES` requires a full string match.

You can fix the code with

```swift
extension String {
    var isValidUsername: Bool {
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@ ", "[A-Za-z0-9!@#$%^&*()._-]{5,16}")
        return predicate.evaluate(with: self)
    }
}
```