# How do I set password Rules when signing up using Parse and Swift?

Tags: swift, parse-platform, passwords, back4app

This is the code I have thus far. When I run the code it still allows me to choose a password that does not follow the rules. I believe it is because the code is just specifically swift not swift and parse. I also need to validate but cannot find anything out there specifically parse related.

```
 @IBAction func signUp(_ sender: Any){
    let user = PFUser()
    user.username = emailField.text!
    user.password = passwordField.text!
    user.email = emailField.text!
    
    // customizing password rules
    passwordField.passwordRules = UITextInputPasswordRules(descriptor: "required: upper; required: lower; required: digit; required: [-().&@?'#,/&quot;+]; minlength: 8;")
```

Comment: Follow what rules? Please clarify what the issue is.

Comment: at least 1 lower case, 1 upper case, 1 digit, 1 special character, and min length of 8

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62425699/9223839) is one way to do it

Answer (score 0):

You need to define this rule in your server.

In your Parse Server, add following `passwordPolicy` object to server config in index.js like below:

```
var api = new ParseServer({
   ...
  passwordPolicy: {
    validatorPattern: /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.{8,})/, // enforce password with at least 8 char with at least 1 lower case, 1 upper case and 1 digit
    validationError: 'Şifreniz en az 1 küçük harf 1 büyük harf 1 özel işaret 1 sayı içermeli ve 8 karakter uzunluğunda olmalı.', // optional error message to be sent instead of the default "Password does not meet the Password Policy requirements." message.
    doNotAllowUsername: true // optional setting to disallow username in passwords
  }
   ...
  });
```

Comment: How can I implement this on swift

Comment: I am building an app and using back4app

Comment: You need to go server settings -> Custom Parse Server Options in your back4app panel. You need to add passwordPolicy object to there.